# Custom Authorize Attribute fires only once

Tags: asp.net, authentication, caching

so here is my problem when i login to site and visit page at first time my attribute is work and second time when i login to the site with other role there is no firing for authorize attribute..

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthorizationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AuthorizationAttribute(params string[] allowedRoles)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        var result = allowedRoles.Select(x=>x).Where(x=>user.IsInRole(x.ToLower()));
        var isUserInRoles = result.Any();
        if (isUserInRoles) return;
        //if user is admin and allowed role is admin
        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser().Any() && allowedRoles.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Contains(UserRoles.Admin.ToLower()))
            return;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPages/AccessDenied.aspx");
    }
```

and on the page

```
 [Authorization(UserRoles.RegionManager)]
```

Comment: Are you registering this attribute or filter globally (that is, in the `FilterConfig` file, for example)?

Comment: Also, are you adding the custom filter to your controller class? (What is "*page*")?

Comment: Are you using MVC? There is already an [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) that does all this for you.

Comment: no i'm using webforms

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am facing same problem.